# AngularJS. Input с value пустой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Нужно сделать простой калькулятор.
Делал так:

```
<input type="number" value="25" ng-model="first">
<input type="number" value="25" ng-model="second">
<h1>{{first + second}}</h1>
```

Считает он правильно, но я поставил **value** и при загрузке страницы эти инпуты пустые. Что не так? Или вместо **ng-model** исп. что-то другое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы указали `ng-model` для инпута, то значение всегда будет браться оттуда. Можно присвоить начальные значение через `ng-init`:

```
<input type="number" ng-init="first=25" ng-model="first">
<input type="number" ng-init="second=25" ng-model="second">
<h1>{{first + second}}</h1>
```

Или в контроллере (в большинстве случаев более правильный подход)

```
// JS
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.first = 25;
  $scope.second = 25;
});

// HTML
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="first">
  <input type="number" ng-model="second">
  <h1>{{first + second}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: тогда атрибут value убери, он все равно не нужен

Comment: @Grundy убрал спс